# Max-width of Select Options

Tags: html, css

I am trying to limit the length of the items of the Select Dropdown.

Here is an example: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/jhernandis/pen/vGpLpr)

It looks like there can only be a max-width on the Select item and not on the Option items.

```
.maxwidth > option {
  max-width:150px;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible with the default browser `<select>` for more info read this post: [How to style the option of an html "select" element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-an-html-select-element)

You can either choose to use a library with a customizable select or make a select element yourself with javascript.